# symmetric matrix multiplication

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

I have three matrices $A$, $H$, and $B$. $A$, $H$, and $B$ are $n$ by $n$ matrices, and $H$ is a symmetric matrix.
Is $A^THB$ equal to $B^THA$?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you're asking. Are you asking if it must be true that  $A^THB=B^THA$? If so, then this is certainly not the case, as you can take any $H$ to be the $n\times n$ identity matrix and let $A$ and $B$ be any $n\times n$ matrices such that $A^TB$ is not symmetric. This is because if $H=I$, then $A^THB=A^TB$ and $B^THA=B^TA=(A^TB)^T$.

Comment: Hi , what if H is not identity matrix?

Answer (score 0):

Oh okay. I see you have edited your question. In general, there is no reason for $A^THB$ to equal $B^THA$. These two matrices are the transposes of each other, so you will have $A^THB=B^THA$ if and only if $A^THB$ is symmetric. You can find several examples where $A^THB$ is not symmetric, even if $H$ is a symmetric matrix other than the identity. For example, let $$A=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
1 & 1 \end{array} \right),\hspace{.5cm}B=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1\\
2 & 1 \end{array} \right),\hspace{.5cm}H=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 2\\
2 & 1 \end{array} \right).$$ Then $$A^THB=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
6 & 6\\
2 & 3 \end{array} \right)\neq\left( \begin{array}{cc}
6 & 2\\
6 & 3 \end{array} \right)=B^THA.$$

It is really not hard to find examples where $A^THB\neq B^THA$. I didn't give any effort for my construction. I just picked some $2\times 2$ matrices off the top of my head, and they turned out to have the property that $A^THB\neq B^THA$.